# R - Predict values for multiple categories of same outcome

Tags: r, prediction, arima, forecast

Lets take ,
I have data of tickets sold in each category for a number of years by months.
Like this:

```
Year         Premium     Silver     Budget
Jan2016      112354      36745      456563       
Feb2016      1233445     234322     4533345
Mar2016      13456544    346755     34564422
```

I have this data till Feb 2019 for each month.
This is the code I use to apply arima for each category separately.
I import the count of each column and do the below:

```
> count <-data.frame(mytickets$Premium)
> tickets<-ts(count, frequency = 12, start = c(2016, 1),end=c(2018,6)) 
> pi=auto.arima(tickets) 
> summary(pi) 
> q=forecast(pi,h=12)
```

I want to predict how many tickets will be sold next year evey month. 
Is it possible to  apply auto ARIMA in the same shot?
I have been applying the model separately so far.

Comment: *"Is it possible to apply auto ARIMA in the same shot?"* I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. Are you asking how to implement some sort of *multivariate* ARIMA model (i.e. a model where you have multiple possibly correlated *dependent* variables)? Or are you asking how to efficiently *code* three different ARIMA models?

Comment: Im looking to efficiently code 3 in to one ARIMA model. I want the predicted values of all the countries in one single shot.

Comment: Can you please include sample data and the code you've got so far; not only will it help us understand what you're trying to do, but it will also gives us something to work with.

Comment: Please don't post code/sample data in comments, as it makes code difficult to read and comments are transient. Instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55176377/edit) your original question and include all critical information in your main post; then delete your last comment.

Comment: done. Please check now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always try `lapply` when you want to calculate multiple things in a similar way:

```
dt <- read.table(text ="Year         Premium     Silver     Budget
Jan2016      112354      36745      456563       
Feb2016      1233445     234322     4533345
Mar2016      13456544    346755     34564422", header = TRUE)

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(dt)
res <- lapply(c("Premium", "Silver", "Budget"), function(x) {
  count <- dt[, get(x)]
  tickets <-
    ts(
      count,
      frequency = 12,
      start = c(2016, 1),
      end = c(2018, 6)
    )
  pi = auto.arima(tickets)
  forecast(pi, h = 12)
})
```

Comment: This is the best!! Thank you very much :)